# Use PHP to $_GET[ID] from URL

Tags: php

i am using simple code to get some data from DB based on some unique ID called VIN.
i wrote a script which work fine if somebody insert it in form, but now i need to edit to work more automaticly, and use $_GET['vin'] from URL and just display results based on that.

My try of code looks like:
public $vin = null;

```
 public function __construct( $data = array() ) {
     if( isset( $data['vin'] ) ) $this->vin = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['vin'] ) );
 }

 public function storeFormValues( $params ) {
    $this->__construct( $params ); 
 }

 public function fetchByVinEvidence($vin) {
     $success = false;
     try{
        $con = new PDO( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS ); 
        $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM evidence_vin WHERE vin = :vin LIMIT 1";
        $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bindValue( "vin", $this->vin, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->execute();
            echo "<table>";
            echo "<th>First Registration</th>";
            echo "<th>Validity Until</th>";
            echo "<th>Rpm</th>";
            echo "<th>Max-Speed</th>";
            echo "<th>Action</th>";
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>24</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['claim_number']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['license']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['country']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['vin']."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>" ;
            }catch(PDOExeption $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
            echo $con->errorInfo();
            }

         return $success;
     }
```

and call the function:

```
$vin = $_GET['vin'];
echo $vin;
$data = new Data;
$data->fetchByVinEvidence($vin);
```

Can somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass a variable `$vin` to the function `fetchByVinEvidence` but then use the class level variable `$this->vin` instead of the passed one.

```
$stmt->bindValue( "vin", $this->vin, PDO::PARAM_STR );
```

should be

```
$stmt->bindValue( "vin", $vin, PDO::PARAM_STR );
```

**OR** set the class level variable to the passed one at the start of the function if you need to use it elsehwere:

```
public function fetchByVinEvidence($vin) {
     $this->vin = $vin;
     ....
```

Comment: It works, thanks man. Can i ask what was difference? $this->vin is object and and $vin is not or what?

Comment: `$this->vin` referes to the class level variable, whereas `$vin` refers to the method level variable (the one you passed to it)

Comment: If i am using something like this, its not much secure, am i right?
Should i add something like this for calling function:
`$vin = stripslashes( strip_tags( $_GET['vin']) );`

Comment: No need, you are using prepared statements, if something wierd is passed, the query will simply return no results.

Comment: Thanks for help, i am a bit more clever again :D  cya

Answer (score 1):

```
 public function __construct( $data = array() ) {
     if( isset( $data['vin'] ) ) $this->vin = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['vin'] ) );
 }
```

__construct if waiting for an array, give it your $_GET directly :

```
$data = new Data($_GET); // and not $_GET['vin'] as it was the case before my edit
$data->fetchByVinEvidence($vin);
```

It was giving null because you didn't send anything to your constructor, so it used the default value : an empty array.

Comment: whilst this will work, it would be confusing, because the method `fetchByVinEvidence` would except a variable but ignore it.

Comment: @user574632 Wasn't it confusing that the fetchByVinEvidence was expecting a variable but using $this->vin ? :) I think it's just a misunderstanding of OOP with code snippets that led to a confusing code overall.

Comment: I already used work of user574632, but giving u thumb up for trying to help me. Anyway i have question. If i use just $_GET not $_GET['id'] and my URL looks as `.php?vin=WAUZZZ8E74A028540&action=evidence`will it work?

Comment: @ClémentMalet yes, i agree

Comment: @MartinFerko $_GET is an array with every parameters sent in URL, so yes it would work anyway. You're checking if $data['vin'] is set which is a good thing, your code is pretty solid.